# Convexity of the root of a complicated term

Tags: convex-analysis, quadratic-forms, convex-cone

I am currently trying to prove the convexity of the following function of x, and I unfortunately have problems finding a solution

$$
\sqrt{\mathbf{x^{\top}}\mathbf{Q} \mathbf{x} + 2(\boldsymbol{\sigma_1} - \sigma_{nn} \mathbf{1_1})^{\top}\mathbf{x} + \sigma_{nn}},
$$

with $x, \sigma_1 \in \mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ and $\sigma_{nn} \in \mathbb{R}$ and $1_1 \in \mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ the vector consisting only of ones, $\mathbf{Q}$ a positive definite matrix.
Does somebody maybe have an idea how to solve this? I would be very thankful!

Comment: you could show that the level set $\{ x; f(x) \le c\}$ is convex for all $c$. This allows for squaring that root term

Comment: Shouldn't there be any conditions in the $\sigma$ such that there term under the root is always non-negative?

Comment: There have to be the above mentioned conditions: consider $n = 2$, $Q = 1$, $\sigma_1 = 6$ and $\sigma_{nn} = 2$, then the function is $\sqrt{x^2 + 4 x + 2}$. The line segment connecting $(\sqrt{2} - 2, f(\sqrt{2} - 2) = 0)$ and $(0, f(0) = \sqrt{2})$ lies completely under the graph of the function, so $f$ is not convex.